# Responsive background image in Twig template

Tags: 8, theming, media

I would like to render an image as background image in my Twig template. To optimize my resources I'd like to use a responsive image but I cannot find a way to use it for background images.

For a standard image I would use something like

```
img src="{{ file_url(node.field_with_image.entity.uri.value) }}" alt="my_alt" class="my_class">
```

How can I achieve that with a background image?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a look at [Background Images Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter).

> It contains a submodule to handle responsive images as well.

Either use that or check how they are doing it.

Comment: Is there any way to access the image within the twig with something like {{ content.my_field }} ?

Comment: Something like {{ node.my_field.entity.uri.value | image_style('thumbnail') }} but for responsive images ?

Comment: Has anybody tried Background Images Formatter. Id like to do the same thing but this doesnt work-  | responsive_image('')